# If $f$ is defined with: $f:u\to(u(2), u'(2)) $ find all the solutions to $f(u)=(3,-2)$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces

If f is an linear operator $f:ℝ[x]\toℝ^2$ which is defined with:
$f:u\to(u(2), u'(2)) $ find all the solutions to $f(u)=(3,-2)$.

So I started like this:

$u(x)=a_0+a_1x+\dots+a_nx^n$

$u'(x)=a_1+2a_2x+3a_3x^2+\dots+na_nx^{n-1}$

$u(2)=a_0+2a_1+\dots+2^na_n=3$

$u'(2)=a_1+2^2a_2+3\times2^2a_3+\dots+na_n2^{n-1}=-2$

So the solution to the equation are all polynomials whose coefficients satisfy the above equations. We can see that the zero polynomial doesn't satisfy the equations so the solutions are not a subspace.

$\sum_{k=0}^{n} 2^{k}a_{k} = 3$

$\sum_{k=1}^{n} 2^{k-1}ka_{k} = -2$

From the second sum, $a_1=-2-\sum_{k=2}^{n} 2^{k-1}ka_{k}$.
Now we use that in the first sum:

$a_0+2a_1+\sum_{k=2}^{n} 2^{k}a_{k}=3$

$a_{0}=3-2\times (-2-\sum_{k=2}^{n} 2^{k-1} k a_{k})=7+\sum_{k=2}^{n} 2^ka_k(k-1)$

So all the solutions are in

$\begin{bmatrix}
           7 \\
           -2 \\
           0 \\
           0 \\
           \vdots \\
           0
         \end{bmatrix} +L(\{
\begin{bmatrix}
           8 \\
           -4 \\
           1 \\
           0 \\
           \vdots \\
           0
         \end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
           24 \\
           -12 \\
           0 \\
           1 \\
           \vdots \\
           0
         \end{bmatrix}, \dots , 
\begin{bmatrix}
           2^nn \\
           -2^{n-1}n \\
           0 \\
           0 \\
           \vdots \\
           1
         \end{bmatrix}\})$ in respect to basis $\{1,x,x^2,\dots,x^n\}$.

Is this correct and is there any better way of solving this?

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is correct. A smoother way would be the following:

As you have observed this is a linear inhomogeneous problem: Find all $u(x)\in{\mathbb R}[x]$ satisfying $u(2)=3$, $u'(2)=-2$. The philosophy for such problems is the following: The general solution is the sum of the general solution of the associated homogeneous problem plus a particular solution of the given inhomogeneous problem.

The associated homogeneous problem is the following: Find all polynomials $u(x)$ satisfying 
$$u(2)=0,\quad u'(2)=0\ .$$
These are obviouslay the polynomials having $(x-2)^2$ as a factor:
$$u_{\rm hom}(x)=(x-2)^2 p(x),\qquad p(x)\in{\mathbb R}[x]\ .$$
A particular solution can be guessed as
$$u_{\rm part}(x)=3-2(x-2)=7-2x\ .$$
It follows that the general solution of your problem is given by
$$u(x)=u_{\rm hom}(x)+u_{\rm part}(x)=(x-2)^2 p(x)+7-2x,\qquad p(x)\in{\mathbb R}[x]\ .$$

Comment: This is definitely more intuitive and with less work. But is my result correct?